# Xamarin Android: Save Facebook Access Token in strings.xml

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've searched on google on how to dynamically edit the Resources.Values.strings.xml file so I can add my Facebook Access Token so the user won't need to log in again when he reuses the app. 
Is it possible to edit it, or do I have to use another method to store the token?

Comment: and you not use the `Xamarin.Auth` nuget package for this that will sort out all Facebook Authentication and storing of tokens? [https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth)

Comment: I am using Facebook SDK https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk

Answer (score 5):

I think the best place would be to save this to the `KeyStore`. To do this you must use the `DependencyService` [More Info here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/)

The interface and implementation would then be:

**PCL interface**

```
public interface IAuth
{
    void CreateStore();
    IEnumerable<string> FindAccountsForService(string serviceId);
    void Save(string pin,string serviceId);
    void Delete(string serviceId);
}
```

**Android**

```
public class IAuthImplementation : IAuth
{
    Context context;
    KeyStore ks;
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection prot;

    static readonly object fileLock = new object();

    const string FileName = "MyProg.Accounts";
    static readonly char[] Password = null;

    public void CreateStore()
    {

        this.context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        ks = KeyStore.GetInstance(KeyStore.DefaultType);

        prot = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(Password);

        try
        {
            lock (fileLock)
            {
                using (var s = context.OpenFileInput(FileName))
                {
                    ks.Load(s, Password);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Java.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //ks.Load (null, Password);
            LoadEmptyKeyStore(Password);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> FindAccountsForService(string serviceId)
    {
        var r = new List<string>();

        var postfix = "-" + serviceId;

        var aliases = ks.Aliases();
        while (aliases.HasMoreElements)
        {
            var alias = aliases.NextElement().ToString();
            if (alias.EndsWith(postfix))
            {
                var e = ks.GetEntry(alias, prot) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry;
                if (e != null)
                {
                    var bytes = e.SecretKey.GetEncoded();
                    var password = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                    r.Add(password);
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public void Delete(string serviceId)
    {
        var alias = MakeAlias(serviceId);

        ks.DeleteEntry(alias);
        Save();
    }

    public void Save(string pin, string serviceId)
    {
        var alias = MakeAlias(serviceId);

        var secretKey = new SecretAccount(pin);
        var entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);
        ks.SetEntry(alias, entry, prot);

        Save();
    }

    void Save()
    {
        lock (fileLock)
        {
            using (var s = context.OpenFileOutput(FileName, FileCreationMode.Private))
            {
                ks.Store(s, Password);
            }
        }
    }

    static string MakeAlias(string serviceId)
    {
        return "-" + serviceId;
    }

    class SecretAccount : Java.Lang.Object, ISecretKey
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        public SecretAccount(string password)
        {
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        }
        public byte[] GetEncoded()
        {
            return bytes;
        }
        public string Algorithm
        {
            get
            {
                return "RAW";
            }
        }
        public string Format
        {
            get
            {
                return "RAW";
            }
        }
    }

    static IntPtr id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC;

    void LoadEmptyKeyStore(char[] password)
    {
        if (id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(ks.Class.Handle, "load", "(Ljava/io/InputStream;[C)V");
        }
        IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr intPtr2 = JNIEnv.NewArray(password);
        JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(ks.Handle, id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC, new JValue[]
            {
                new JValue (intPtr),
                new JValue (intPtr2)
            });
        JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(intPtr);
        if (password != null)
        {
            JNIEnv.CopyArray(intPtr2, password);
            JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(intPtr2);
        }
    }
```

Call Create Store in the main activity of Android app first. - This could possibly be improved and remove CreateStrore() from the interface by checking if ks == null in Save and Delete and calling the method if true

This would then save the access token to the `KeyStore` that you can then retrieve later

Comment: Thank you for the input. I did not know about the Keystore and I've read about it, but in the meantime I've used PreferenceManager as I read that is a good solution as well.